# Dropping keyspace from data directory

Tags: cassandra

Hello i am new to cassandra. i am trying to drop a keyspace from data directory. I know a way to delete keyspace from cqlsh but the problem is my cassandra is down due to following error.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.apache.cassandra.db:type=Tables,keyspace=test_keyspace
```

I have deleted the keyspace form data directory but as i start my server the deleted keyspace is again present in the dir so i cant completely delete the keyspace.

Thank you in advance <3

Comment: Is it in the `system_schema.keyspaces` table?  Check with: `> SELECT * FROm system_schema.keyspaces;`. If so, that means it hasn't been dropped properly via cqlsh.

Comment: @Aaron I cant access the server with cqlsh as it is in down state.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Deleting the keyspace directory on disk is not the correct procedure for dropping a keyspace.

It is not clear to me exactly what the problem is or what you're trying to achieve but it seems that you're trying to fix two different issues.

In any case, the only way to drop a keyspace is via CQL. Cheers!

Comment: My problem is that my cassandra server is in failed state due to above error. To delete the keyspace from cql, i cannnot connect the server as it is in failed state. So my question is, is there any otherway to delete the keyspace?

Comment: The challenge for us is that there isn't enough detail in your question. I suggest editing your original post with (1) the full error message AND (2) full stack trace. It is also customary to provide the C* version you're running. Cheers!